# Wikitude SDK - markers are not showing in the camera view

Tags: android, marker, wikitude

I created a simple app following the POI example in Wikitude. When I run the application, no markers are painted on the camera view. I have the same issue with the sample POI app as well. I have put some JS alerts in the js file inside the '`onLocationChangedFn`' and the '`createMarkerAtLocation`' functions and the alerts show up properly (which hopefully means that the javascript functions are being called properly. But still the marker doesn't show at the geo location.

I see the following in the logcat in Eclipse:

```
09-21 11:32:50.809: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1255K, 29% free 8947K/12551K, paused 18ms, total 19ms

09-21 11:32:50.839: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_CONCURRENT freed 15K, 24% free 9561K/12551K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 33ms

09-21 11:32:50.849: E/deviceSupported(6108): true

09-21 11:32:50.849: I/ArchitectWebView(6108): ARchitect Build: d4452f2

09-21 11:32:50.919: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_CONCURRENT freed 561K, 22% free 9826K/12551K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 33ms

09-21 11:32:50.919: D/dalvikvm(6108): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 9ms

09-21 11:32:50.939: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 733K, 21% free 9920K/12551K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
09-21 11:32:50.969: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_CONCURRENT freed 608K, 20% free 10147K/12551K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 30ms
09-21 11:32:50.969: D/dalvikvm(6108): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms

09-21 11:32:51.049: E/Web Console(6108): Uncaught ReferenceError: AR is not defined at null:1

09-21 11:32:51.109: I/Adreno200-EGL(6108): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:299>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic AU_msm8625_REFS/TAGS/JB_REL_RB5_QRD_D20130228_CL3285357_release_AU (CL3285357)

09-21 11:32:51.109: I/Adreno200-EGL(6108): Build Date: 03/01/13 Fri

09-21 11:32:51.109: I/Adreno200-EGL(6108): Local Branch:

09-21 11:32:51.109: I/Adreno200-EGL(6108): Remote Branch: m/refs/tags/jb_rel_rb5_qrd_D20130228
09-21 11:32:51.109: I/Adreno200-EGL(6108): Local Patches: NONE

09-21 11:32:51.109: I/Adreno200-EGL(6108): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING

09-21 11:32:51.179: E/libEGL(6108): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

09-21 11:32:51.179: W/Adreno200-ES20(6108): <qgl2DrvAPI_glHint:90>: GL_INVALID_ENUM

09-21 11:32:51.179: E/libEGL(6108): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API

09-21 11:32:52.289: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1121K, 23% free 9784K/12551K, paused 19ms, total 22ms
09-21 11:32:52.949: E/BufferQueue(6108): [unnamed-6108-1] dequeueBuffer: mMinUndequeuedBuffers=2 exceeded (dequeued=6)
09-21 11:32:52.949: I/Choreographer(6108): Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-21 11:32:52.979: E/BufferQueue(6108): [unnamed-6108-1] dequeueBuffer: mMinUndequeuedBuffers=2 exceeded (dequeued=5)
09-21 11:32:55.139: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 867K, 25% free 9523K/12551K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
09-21 11:32:55.199: D/dalvikvm(6108): GC_CONCURRENT freed 8K, 22% free 10918K/13959K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 47ms

09-21 11:33:08.909: E/Web Console(6108): Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onLocationChanged' of object [object Object] is not a function at null:1

09-21 11:33:08.909: E/Web Console(6108): Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onLocationChanged' of object [object Object] is not a function at null:1
```

I see two issues in the above log: one regarding the `"unimplemented OpenGL ES API"` and the other regarding `"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'onLocationChanged' "`

Are those the reasons for the marker not showing up? How do I fix those and get the marker on the screen. Please help ...

Here is the source code of the index.html that I created following the tutorial at 
http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk/samples-tutorials/architect-tutorial-3-geo-ar-poi/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width = 540, user-scalable = 0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <script src="architect://architect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ade.js"></script>
    <script>
        <!-- Javascript function defining a click handler -->
        function messageClicked() {
            // set the message DIV text
            document.getElementById("messageElement").innerHTML = "My text";
        }
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
/* CSS Style for the message DIV that displays our message */
        .message {
        border-radius: 2em;
        border: solid 1px #6d6d6d;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
        color: black;
        text-align: center;

        position:absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 10%;
        left: 25%;
        top: 45%;
        }
}
</style>
</head>

<body class="custom">

    <div id="messageElement" class="message" onClick="messageClicked();">
        Hello World!
    </div>

    <script>
        AR.context.onLocationChanged = function(lat, lon, alt, acc) {
        // the current location's latitude, longitude, altitude and accuracy
        // are passed in by the ARchitect
        var myGeoLocation = new AR.RelativeLocation(null, 10, 0, 0);
        var myCircle = new AR.Circle(5, {style: {fillColor: '#FFC100'}});
        var myGeoObject = new AR.GeoObject(myGeoLocation, {drawables: {cam: myCircle}});
        //AR.context.onLocationChanged = null;
        // Hide loading message
        //document.getElementById("messageElement").style.display="none";
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Uncaught TypeError` output is logged because of an error while executing your JavaScript code. If you post the code we might be able to tell you what's wrong.

Some things to check:

1. is the `architect.js` included correctly
2. have you used the API correctly (e.g. forgot to add the namespace `AR`)
3. use the `ade.js` that comes with the SDK to test on a desktop browser (it provides a much better debugging experience).

*Disclaimer: I work for Wikitude.*

Comment: wulfgeng, thanks for the response. I think I am doing all of the above correctly since I have used the sammple code verbatim just to start with something. I have posted the same question in the wikitude forum as well and have provided the source code there. I am providing the link of that post here. Let me know if you want me to post the code here.  [Wikitude post](http://studio.wikitude.com/web/forum/developer-forum/-/message_boards/message/347644)

Comment: I have figured out why the `Uncaught TypeError` was happening. It was because of the very first thing the `onLocationChangedFn` function does: `AR.context.onLocationChanged = null;` Once I removed that line, the error went away. But the original issue of the marker not showing at the location is still there. The only reason I could think of is the `called unimplemented OpenGL ES API` error in logcat.

Comment: Just to make sure what I am doing is correct, I again started from the Hello World [tutorial](http://www.wikitude.com/products/wikitude-sdk/samples-tutorials/). The first 2 tutorials worked just fine and I was able to see the head up display on the camera view. Then I proceeded to the 3rd tutorial to display the POI marker. I finished everything according to the tutorial and tried it on the device. The same issue happened: no POI marker on the camera view and `called unimplemented OpenGL ES API` error in logcat. I tried in 3 different devices just to make sure with the same result. I am stuck.

Comment: I have posted the source code of the index.html that I created following the tutorial in my original post.

Comment: @wulfgeng I am facing the same issue however this only happens when I dismiss a dialog before showing/rendering a marker.

Answer (score 1):

when I have this issue, it was because I missed to add these functions:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.architectView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.architectView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.architectView.onDestroy();
}


//my own function
private void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
    try {
        //MAKE SURE YOU CALL THIS
        architectView.setLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(), location.getAccuracy());
        this.architectView.load("poi_1/index.html");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```